# Unable to start activity ComponentInfo when new activity is called: NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-intent, nullpointerexception, android-activity, android-sqlite

I am getting this error when i call a new activity via intent and sending values via intent
here i gave the class calling nw class and their codes separately please check the log cat too i am getting force close i am using android version 4.0.3

#### Activity calling another activity when btnf is called

```
package dlp.android.digichronicle;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.method.ScrollingMovementMethod;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class displ extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
    Button btnf;// done
    TextView tvf;// ok
    EditText edtf, edt2;// db txt

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    DBHandandler myDbHelper = new DBHandandler(this);
    SQLiteDatabase Mydatabase;
    String stattionlist, s1;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.displ);
        tvf = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvf);
        edtf = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtf);
        edt2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt2);
        btnf = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnf);
        btnf.setOnClickListener(this);
        first();
    }

    private void first() {
        String s1 = "", s2 = second.ge;
        this.myDbHelper = new DBHandandler(this);
        try {
            FetchingData();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        myDbHelper.openDataBase();
        Mydatabase = myDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        System.out.println("executed");
        Mydatabase = myDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        System.out.println("sure2");// debug info
        // calling open() function which will show the text in table in EditText
        // using SetText method
        // Function is defined in DBHanadanler.java file
        if (s2.equalsIgnoreCase("memo")) {
            s1 = myDbHelper.open("memo", Mydatabase);
            System.out.println("Called memo" + s1 + s2);
        }
        else if (s2.equalsIgnoreCase("reminder"))
            s1 = myDbHelper.open("reminder", Mydatabase);
        else if (s2.equalsIgnoreCase("tasks"))
            s1 = myDbHelper.open("tasks", Mydatabase);
        else if (s2.equalsIgnoreCase("events"))
            s1 = myDbHelper.open("events", Mydatabase);
        else if (s2.equalsIgnoreCase("accounts"))
            s1 = myDbHelper.open("accounts", Mydatabase);
        System.out.println("after open");

        edtf.setText(s1);
        System.out.println("string is : " + s1 + "2nd time");// debug info
        edtf.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
        tvf.setText(s2);
    }

    // call the method which is present in datbase
    private void FetchingData() throws SQLException {

        try {
            myDbHelper.onCreateDataBase();

        } catch (IOException ioe) {

            throw new Error("Unable to create database");

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (v == btnf)
        {
            s1 = edtf.getText().toString();

            Intent i3 = new Intent(displ.this, inter.class);
            i3.putExtra("value", s1);
            startActivity(i3);

        }

    }
}
```

#### Newly called activity class

```
package dlp.android.digichronicle;

import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class inter extends Activity {
    DBHandandler myDbHelper;
    SQLiteDatabase Mydatabase;
    String s;
    String stattionlist, DBname = "widgets";

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
        System.out.println(b);
        if (b != null)
        {
            s = b.getString("value");
            System.out.println("INtermediate" + s);
            Log.e("xxxx2", s);
            try {
                FetchingData();
                myDbHelper.openDataBase();
                System.out.println("****** After open db");
                Mydatabase = myDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                System.out.println("###### after writable");

                System.out.println("###### updated string :" + s);
                String s2 = second.ge;

                if (s2.equalsIgnoreCase("memo")) {
                    myDbHelper.updateevent("memo", Mydatabase, s);
                    System.out.println("Called memo" + s2 + s);
                }
                else if (s2.equalsIgnoreCase("reminder"))
                    myDbHelper.updateevent("reminder", Mydatabase, s);
                else if (s2.equalsIgnoreCase("tasks"))
                    myDbHelper.updateevent("tasks", Mydatabase, s);
                else if (s2.equalsIgnoreCase("events"))
                    myDbHelper.updateevent("events", Mydatabase, s);
                else if (s2.equalsIgnoreCase("accounts"))
                    myDbHelper.updateevent("accounts", Mydatabase, s);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "updated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            myDbHelper.close();
            Mydatabase.close();
            Intent i3 = new Intent(inter.this, second.class);
            startActivity(i3);
            System.out.println("button end btnf");
        }
        // stattionlist=this.myDbHelper.updateevent(Mydatabase,s1);
        // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext()," "+s1,100).show();

    }

    private void FetchingData() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            myDbHelper.onCreateDataBase();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            throw new Error("Unable to create database");
        }
        try {
            myDbHelper.openDataBase();
            Mydatabase = myDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            System.out.println("executed");
        } catch (SQLException sqle) {
            throw sqle;
        }
    }

    // Intent i2=new Intent(intermediate.this,second.class);
    // startActivity(i2);
}
```

#### Database Helper class

```
package dlp.android.digichronicle; // ur package name

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class DBHandandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/dlp.android.digichronicle/databases/";
    private static String DB_NAME = "widget.sqlite";
    private static String TABLENAME = "widgets";
    private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;
    private final Context myContext;
    public static final String KEY_MEM = "memo";
    public static final String KEY_TAS = "tasks";
    public static final String KEY_REM = "reminder";
    public static final String KEY_EVE = "events";
    public static final String KEY_DAT = "dated";
    public static final String KEY_INC = "income";
    public static final String KEY_EXP = "exp";
    ArrayList<String> sw;
    String s = "";

    public DBHandandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.myContext = context;
    }

    public int onCreateDataBase() throws IOException
    {
        boolean dbExist = checkDatabase();
        if (dbExist) {
            return 0;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("onCreateDataBase method execution starts");
            this.getReadableDatabase();
            copyDataBase();
            return 1;

        }
    }

    private boolean checkDatabase() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
        try
        {
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
        if (checkDB != null) {
            checkDB.close();
        }
        return checkDB != null ? true : false;

    }

    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {

        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

        // Path to the just created empty db
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

        // Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        // transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);

        }

        // Close the streams
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {

        // Open the database
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    }

    public String open(String s3, SQLiteDatabase Mydatabase)
    {
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        System.out.println("b4 string is : " + list);
        String s = "";
        try {
            System.out.println("string got is " + s3);
            String dt = MainActivity.g;
            System.out.println("Date obtained is " + dt);
            Cursor c = Mydatabase.rawQuery("select " + " " + s3 + " "
                    + "from widgets where dated='" + dt + "'", null);
            System.out.println("after cursor");
            if (c.moveToFirst())
            {

                System.out.println("cursor" + c.moveToFirst());
                do {
                    System.out.println("before columnindex");
                    list.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(s3)));
                    System.out.println("after columnindex");
                    System.out.println(" string is :  " + list);

                } while (c.moveToNext());
            }
            c.close();
        } catch (SQLiteException se) {
            Mydatabase.close();
            System.out.println("exception");
        }

        s = list.toString();
        int len = s.length();
        s = s.substring(1, len - 1);
        System.out.println("string is : " + list);
        System.out.println("string is : " + s);
        return s;

    }

    public String eventdia(SQLiteDatabase mydatabase1) {

        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        System.out.println("Event dialogue start " + list);
        String s = "";
        try {
            System.out.println("geting event");
            String dt = MainActivity.g;
            System.out.println("Date obtained in events " + dt);
            Cursor c = mydatabase1.rawQuery("select events from widgets where dated='" + dt + "'",
                    null);

            if (c.moveToFirst())
            {
                System.out.println("cursor" + c.moveToFirst());
                do {
                    list.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("events")));
                    System.out.println(" string is :  " + list);

                } while (c.moveToNext());
            }
            c.close();
        } catch (SQLiteException se) {
            mydatabase1.close();
            System.out.println("exception");
        }

        s = list.toString();
        int len = s.length();
        s = s.substring(1, len - 1);
        System.out.println("string is : " + list);
        System.out.println("string is : " + s);
        return s;
    }

    public String checkin(SQLiteDatabase mydatabase1) {

        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        System.out.println("b4 string is : " + list);
        String s = "";
        try {
            System.out.println("geting event");
            String dt = MainActivity.g;
            System.out.println("Date obtained is" + dt);
            Cursor c = mydatabase1.rawQuery("select events from widgets where dated='" + dt + "'",
                    null);

            if (c.moveToFirst())
            {
                System.out.println("cursor" + c.moveToFirst());
                do {
                    list.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("events")));
                    System.out.println(" string is :  " + list);

                } while (c.moveToNext());
            }
            c.close();
        } catch (SQLiteException se) {
            mydatabase1.close();
            System.out.println("exception");
        }

        s = list.toString();
        int len = s.length();
        s = s.substring(1, len - 1);
        System.out.println("string is : " + list);
        System.out.println("string is : " + s);
        return s;
    }

    public void updateevent(String ge, SQLiteDatabase mydatabase2, String s1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String dt = MainActivity.g;
        System.out.println("###### before query");
        ContentValues cvupdate = new ContentValues();
        cvupdate.put(ge, s1);

        mydatabase2.update(TABLENAME, cvupdate, KEY_DAT + "=" + dt, null);

        // mydatabase2.rawQuery("update widgets set memo="+" "+s1+" "+" where dated='"+dt+"'",null);
        // mydatabase2.rawQuery("update widgets set "+" "+ge+" = "+s1+" "+"where where dated='"+dt+"'",null);
        System.out.println("###### after query");
    }

    // Function inserting new record
    public void Insertinto(SQLiteDatabase mydatabase2, String date, String memo, String tasks,
            String reminder, float income, String events, float exp)
    {
        ContentValues data = createContentValues(date, memo, tasks, reminder, income, events, exp);
        System.out.println("data " + data + "  is ");
        mydatabase2.insert(TABLENAME, null, data);
        System.out.println("record is done ");
    }

    // return a content of the database
    private ContentValues createContentValues(String date, String memo, String tasks,
            String reminder, float income, String events, float exp)
    {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_DAT, date);
        values.put(KEY_MEM, memo);
        values.put(KEY_TAS, tasks);
        values.put(KEY_REM, reminder);
        values.put(KEY_INC, income);
        values.put(KEY_EVE, events);
        values.put(KEY_EXP, exp);
        return values;
    }

    // write ur retreival methods here
}
```

#### Log cat errors

```
D/AndroidRuntime(553): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm(553): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
E/AndroidRuntime(553): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(553): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{dlp.android.digichronicle/dlp.android.digichronicle.inter}: java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(553): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at dlp.android.digichronicle.inter.FetchingData(inter.java:84)
E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at dlp.android.digichronicle.inter.onCreate(inter.java:28)
E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
E/AndroidRuntime(553):    ... 11 more
I/dalvikvm(553): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
I/dalvikvm(553): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
I/dalvikvm(553): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
I/dalvikvm(553): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
I/dalvikvm(553): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
I/dalvikvm(553): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
```

Comment: the error is at `dlp.android.digichronicle.inter.onCreate(inter.java:28)` (find the lowest "Caused by" part if there is one, then find the first line from top to bottom that mentions your code - that's what is causing the error)

Comment: also, consider formatting your code before copy-pasting it; bad indentation makes it very hard to read.

Comment: Just giving an advice. Start class name with Capital letter. (Standard Naming Conventions of Java). It should be Inter.java instead of inter.java

Answer (score 2):

You need to instantiate `myDbHelper` in `inter` Activity's `onCreate()` (You did it in `displ` Activity but not in `inter` Activity):

```
DBHandandler myDbHelper = new DBHandandler(this);
```

since `FetchingData()` @ line 28 calls `myDbHelper.onCreateDataBase();` while it is still not instantiated.

Comment: Thanks sir it was useful but i could not update my databse with the query in updatevent method of dbhelper and the variable ge there is the date that is obtaianed from other class where it serves me as promary key in my database please help me sir

Comment: Yes sir the previous problem is solved and the application is being executed properly but data is not being updated in the database please help me sir. I am in urgent need of it

Comment: This is a different question now, however, are you sure that MainActivity.g has a valid value?

Comment: Yes sir am sure because i could see its value in System.out.println(); in logcat

Comment: If you have no rows that satisfy the condition (KEY_DAT + "=" + dt), no updates are possible (you should use insert in this case)